# pyyaml: dump set without null values

Tags: python, set, pyyaml

By default, pyyaml seems to dump sets like this:

```
test_set: !!set
  member_a: null
  member_b: null
```

However, I would prefer it to do this instead:

```
test_set: !!set {'member_a', 'member_b'}
```

which is valid according to [this](https://quickref.me/yaml) or [this](https://tutorialreference.com/yaml/datatypes/advanced/yaml-sets) guide. What pyyaml currently does is not mentioned in the guides.

How can I achieve that? Is there an option?

I also checked with ruamel, but it seems to do the same as pyyaml here. Also it lacks the `sort_keys=False` option which I need.